# Strongswan VPN from Windows 10: no private key found / 13801

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, strongswan

I am evaluating AWS starting with connectivity.  As AWS VPN solutions would be cumulatively expensive, I thought I'd start DIY with Strongswan.  I already have Strongswan working for our site-to-site (to Cisco ASA5506s) requirements but can't get our mobile remote access working using the native Windows VPN client. Both Windows and Strongswan logging indicate some problem with a certificate but it is issued by letsencrypt and valid.

Hardware:

> Type: Amazon System: Amazon EC2 product: t3.nano v: N/A
> Mobo: Amazon EC2 model: N/A serial: N/A BIOS: Amazon EC2 v: 1.0 date: 10/16/2017

OS:

> Host: aws-edge Kernel: 6.1.0-17-cloud-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/1
> Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)

Strongswan U5.9.8/K6.1.0-17-cloud-amd64

```
# /etc/ipsec.secrets

edge.mydomain.com : ECDSA "/etc/ipsec.d/private/privkey.pem"
%any : EAP "Password27"
```

```
# /etc/ipsec.conf

config setup
    strictcrlpolicy=yes
    uniqueids=no
    charondebug="ike 9"
    #charondebug="ike 4, knl 4, cfg 4, net 4, esp 4, dmn 4,  mgr 4"

conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    auto=route
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536
    esp=aes256-sha1
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=30s

conn roadwarriors
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    ike=aes256gcm16-prfsha384-ecp384!
    esp=aes256gcm16-ecp384!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=900s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=@edge.mydomain.com
    #leftauth=pubkey

    # Acquired via certbot/letsencrypt
    leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/cert.pem

    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=10.8.1.0/24
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    eap_identity=%any
    rightsendcert=never
    rightdns=8.8.8.8
    rightsourceip=10.8.1.32/27
    rightsendcert=never
```

Windows VPN configuration:

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://valid-isrgrootx1.letsencrypt.org

Add-VpnConnection -Name edge.mydomain.com  -ServerAddress "edge.mydomain.com" `
-TunnelType IKEv2 -EncryptionLevel Maximum -AuthenticationMethod Eap -RememberCredential

Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration -ConnectionName edge.mydomain.com `
-AuthenticationTransformConstants GCMAES256 `
-CipherTransformConstants GCMAES256 `
-EncryptionMethod GCMAES256 `
-IntegrityCheckMethod SHA384 -DHGroup ECP384 -PfsGroup ECP384 -Force

Set-VpnConnection -Name edge.mydomain.com -SplitTunneling $true
```

Server Certificate; hex blocks omitted, domain obfuscated:

```
# openssl x509 -in /etc/ipsec.d/certs/cert.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            <hex block>
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  9 18:09:49 2024 GMT
            Not After : Apr  8 18:09:48 2024 GMT
        Subject: CN = edge.<mydomain>.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    <hex block>
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                <hex block>
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                <hex block>
            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://r3.o.lencr.org
                CA Issuers - URI:http://r3.i.lencr.org/
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:edge.king-ent.com
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : <hex block>
                    Timestamp : Jan  9 19:09:49.433 2024 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                <hex block>
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : <hex block>
                    Timestamp : Jan  9 19:09:49.437 2024 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                <hex block>
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        <hex block>
```

Converted to .p12 and viewed in Windows:
[image]

Windows RasClient log:

```
CoId={894815C0-439C-0000-0CA0-48899C43DA01}: The user <userid> has started dialing a VPN connection using a per-user connection profile named edge.mydomain.com. The connection settings are: 
Dial-in User = <notmyname>
VpnStrategy = IKEv2
DataEncryption = Require maximum
PrerequisiteEntry = 
AutoLogon = No
UseRasCredentials = Yes
Authentication Type = EAP <Microsoft: Secured password (EAP-MSCHAP v2)>
Ipv4DefaultGateway = No
Ipv4AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv4DNSServerAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DefaultGateway = No
Ipv6AddressAssignment = By Server
Ipv6DNSServerAssignment = By Server
IpDnsFlags = 
IpNBTEnabled = Yes
UseFlags = Private Connection
ConnectOnWinlogon = No
Mobility enabled for IKEv2 = Yes.

...

The user <userid> dialed a connection named edge.mydomain.com which has failed. **The error code returned on failure is 13801**.
```

On the server, journalctl -S now -f:

```
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[CFG] selected peer config 'roadwarriors'
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] initiating EAP_IDENTITY method (id 0x00)
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] processing INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS attribute
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] processing INTERNAL_IP4_DNS attribute
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] processing INTERNAL_IP4_NBNS attribute
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] processing INTERNAL_IP4_SERVER attribute
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] processing INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS attribute
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] processing INTERNAL_IP6_DNS attribute
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] processing INTERNAL_IP6_SERVER attribute
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[IKE] **no private key found** for 'edge.mydomain.com'
Jan 10 18:58:39 aws-edge charon[1006]: 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
```

Comment: "This error can occur due to the following:

The machine certificate used for IKEv2 validation on the RAS server doesn't have Server Authentication enabled under Enhanced Key Usage.
The machine certificate on the RAS server expired.
The client machine doesn't have the root certificate for validating the RAS server certificate.
The client machine's VPN server name doesn't match the subjectName value on the server certificate." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/troubleshoot-always-on-vpn#error-13801-the-ike-authentication-credentials-are-invalid

Comment: @GregAskew, I thought you might be on to something when an openssl dump showed "TLS Web Server Authentication" and not "Server Authentication".  But `ipsec listcerts` just shows "serverAuth", converted to .p12 Windows shows it as "server authentication", and a brief read of the RFC seems to indicate there is only one kind of server authentication.  But thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The certificate uses an ECDSA key:

```
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub:
                <hex block>
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
            NIST CURVE: P-256
```

So you can't load the private key with `RSA` but have to use `ECDSA` instead (you also don't have to use any identities for this):

```
: ECDSA "/etc/ipsec.d/private/privkey.pem"
```

Comment: Username checks out!

Comment: The name is the answer - how often does that happen??!!.  Thanks, and I have corrected the configuration above for posterity.  I will log an issue with https://github.com/jawj/IKEv2-setup where I got the config.

Comment: By the way, an alternative is to request an RSA key from Let's Encrypt (e.g. via `--key-type rsa` when using `certbot`). This might be necessary anyway depending on your clients because e.g. iOS/macOS currently has issues with ECDSA server certificates. Also not that when using swanctl.conf the private key can be loaded in a way that the key type doesn't matter (on the server, clients still might have issues).

Answer (score 2):

You need to [specify the private key in `ipsec.secrets`](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Ipsecsecrets):

```
P12 /etc/ipsec.d/certs/cert.key
```

You only specified certificate, but to use the certificate you need the private key.

Comment: Oh, good catch, Vidario!  But, alas, I already had it specified.  Must have cut it out when I posted.  I will edit my post.  And thanks!

Comment: And it still complains it has no key?

Comment: Yes, same errors at both ends.